# Multiple sequential jobs in a shell script to be cronned in a conditional manner

Tags: shell, cron

I have 31 shell scripts named runner1.sh..runner31.sh . I need to create a cron job and put all of these .sh script run sequential with the condition that they must run if they are not already running and meanwhile if runnerX fails it should stop and not start running runnerX+1.

I've write a shell script for aggregation of these tasks as follow, but I'm not sure whether this is the correct solution:

```
ps -ef |grep -i grep | grep runner1.sh && echo "not to start" && sh runner1.sh && sh runner2.sh && sh runner3.sh && sh runner4.sh && sh runner5.sh && sh runner6.sh && sh runner7.sh && sh runner8.sh && sh runner9.sh && sh runner10.sh && sh runner11.sh && sh runner12.sh && sh runner13.sh && sh runner14.sh && sh runner15.sh && sh runner16.sh && sh runner17.sh && sh runner18.sh && sh runner19.sh && sh runner20.sh && sh runner21.sh && sh runner22.sh && sh runner23.sh && sh runner24.sh && sh runner25.sh && sh runner26.sh && sh runner27.sh && sh runner28.sh && sh runner29.sh && sh runner30.sh && sh runner31.sh
```

Please tell me whether this method is correct or the solution is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a series of runnerX.sh scripts that you need to invoke sequentially.

```
for i in $(seq 1 31); do
   sh runner$i.sh || break
done
```

This covers running them in sequential order, and not running the next one of the prior one fails.

To make sure that the basic runner1.sh is not running, you do:

```
pid=$(ps -fe | grep '[r]unner1.sh' | awk '{print $2}')
```

or

```
pid=$(pgrep runner1.sh)
```

or any of a wide variety of mechanisms for detecting the pid of runner1.sh

combined, you surround the `for` loop with an:

```
if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
  # do for here
  :
fi
```